# Remove all paragraph tags

Tags: formatting

I have content where the paragraphs are all messed up since the WordPress visual editor doesn't work well with pre-existing markup.

I would therefore like to remove the paragraph tags, while leaving the bullet points, hyperlinks and bold formatting, so that I can re-import my content and then hopefully space it out with the visual editor manually.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

(obviously) untested, and make a backup of your DB first...but you ought to be able to do this natively in SQL:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '<p>', '')
WHERE (put whatever selection logic you want here...)
```

Do the same for `</p>`.  Like I said...make a backup first...

(edit) geez, didn't realize this was a year-old question...sorry, for some reason it was edited and at the top of the active questions list...